# How to get a halo of light effect?

Tags: effect, weather, sunlight, halos

I would like to know how to make this effect, and also if it is posible to get it with an iPhone 5s. Thank you.

[image]
(it's from someone else)

Answer (score 5):

This is not a digitally-created effect; this is a physical atmospheric phenomenon called a [sun halo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_(optical_phenomenon)) or 22.5° halo. It occurs when there's a thin layer of high-altitude cirrus clouds with hexagonal ice crystals that refract the passing sunlight, creating a rainbow-like effect.

The image you posted is a particularly good example of the phenomenon; it has a very clear range of colors, and it's high in the sky (at midday).

Another key feature of sun halos is that the inside of the ring is noticeably darker (except for the sun and its glare) than the area immediately surrounding the ring. The image you posted demonstrates this as well.

This halo would look exactly the same to the naked eye. It has nothing to do with cameras or lenses, so there is no technique to reproduce it and no special equipment needed to capture it. If it occurs, a person with an iPhone can take a good picture of it.

Comment: To expand slightly: In case it wasn't totally clear from "atmospheric phenomenon", this halo would look exactly the same to the naked eye. It has nothing to do with cameras or lenses, so there is no technique to reproduce it and no special equipment needed to capture it (if it occurs, an iPhone will take a good picture of it).